# Forcing to cut the record to the next page - Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm hoping you all have a very fine day. Well, I also hope that it is a fine day for me to find solutions to my problem.

I have a requirement on the report I'm doing right now that make me feel miserable. Is it possible to control the showing of data in the Crystal Report?. To be clear with, I have a Declaration Form which requires 9 rows only per page ( to be filled with description, countrycode, etc.). Let's say that the Description of the first item (record) extends to 4th row (4 rows) and the description of the second item shall extend to the 11th row (7 rows). Because the form only permits 9 rows to be filled with data, the description of the second item should be shown such that the first 5 rows is on the first page together with the description of the first item (4 rows) while the 6th and the 7th row of the description will be displayed on the second page.

To elaborate more:

[First Page]

Item 1   This description extends       [country code]           [etc]

```
        to the 4th row of this

        form. And so it won't be

        cut.
```

Item 2   This description extends        [country code]          [etc]

```
        to the 11th row of this

        form. And so it will be

        cut. The problem is how

        can I cut this description
```

[Second Page]

```
        such that the continuation

        will be shown here.
```

Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the form fields to be suppressed when blank in the Format menu. This way the form will only take as much as the information actually takes.

Then uncheck the *Keep together* option on whatever level you operate (Group, Section, Subreport etc.) it should break that element and continue it on the next page.

Comment: But this is not the case. What if I want to break the record and continue it to the next page? because of the size of the allotted space and not because of the size of the paper?. Is it possible to continue to the next page?. What I mean of the allotted size here is the limited space in the middle of the paper and not the whole paper.

Comment: And that should do the job.

Comment: Sorry, run out of time to edit. If the record is a group with Keep Together option unchecked it will print as much information as it can on the page, and the rest will go to the next one. To limit the print area on the page set blank page header and footer to the right size. The record will be printed from the end of the page header to the point where the page footer starts, and the remaining information will go to the next page.

Comment: Still cannot fix the said issue. Let me be clear with the requirement. This is to force a record to be split whenever it occupies nine rows. PS: I have 2 subreports on my crystal report. Please help me with this. I'm trying to solve the issue for a month!.